# Why is com.google.code.kaptcha.Producer.createText() considered a non-accessor method in my SpringBoot REST Controller?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I use com.github.axet:kaptcha:0.0.9 library in my SpringBoot 3.0.5 project. I want to generate image captcha in a method of REST Controller. The code is written in Kotlin.

```
@Configuration
class KaptchaConfig {
    @Bean
    fun producer(): DefaultKaptcha {
        val properties = Properties()
        properties["kaptcha.border"] = "no"
        properties["kaptcha.textproducer.font.color"] = "black"
        properties["kaptcha.textproducer.char.space"] = "4"
        properties["kaptcha.image.height"] = "40"
        properties["kaptcha.image.width"] = "120"
        properties["kaptcha.textproducer.font.size"] = "30"
        return DefaultKaptcha().apply { config = Config(properties) }
    }
}

@RestController
class AuthController {

    @GetMapping("/captcha")
    fun captcha(producer: Producer): CommonResult {
        val key = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val code = producer.createText()
        val codeImage = producer.createImage(code)
        val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        ImageIO.write(codeImage, "jpg", outputStream)

        val base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Base64Encoder.encode(outputStream.toByteArray())
        RedisUtil.hset(Const.CAPTCHA_KEY, key, code, 120)
        
        return CommonResult.ok(buildMap {
            put("token", key)
            put("captchaImg", base64Image)
        })
    }
}
```

Every time I make request to /captcha, I get the following exception:

```
2023-05-19T14:12:03.373+08:00 ERROR 23868 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invoked method public abstract java.lang.String com.google.code.kaptcha.Producer.createText() is no accessor method] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invoked method public abstract java.lang.String com.google.code.kaptcha.Producer.createText() is no accessor method
    at org.springframework.data.projection.Accessor.<init>(Accessor.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.MapAccessingMethodInterceptor.invoke(MapAccessingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectingMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProjectingMethodInterceptor.java:71) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.ProxyProjectionFactory$TargetAwareMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProxyProjectionFactory.java:233) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy90.createText(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at cn.newstar.students.controller.AuthController.captcha(AuthController.kt:20) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:537) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:631) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I found that the `producer` is
[image]
But, when I put the `producer` as member variable `@Autowired private lateinit var producer: Producer`, every thing is OK. In this situation, the `producer` is
[image]

I'm not particularly familiar with SpringBoot. I know that beans can be obtained through the parameters of the constructor, but I don't know if there is any difference in obtaining beans through parameters in the Controller method?